# R match expression multiple times in the same line

Tags: regex, r, twitter

I am working with a set of Tweets (very original, I know) in R and would like to extract the text after each @ sign and after each # and put them into separate variables.  For example:

This is a test tweet using #twitter. @johnsmith @joesmith.

Ideally I would like it to create new variables in the dataframe that has twitter johnsmith joesmith, etc.

Currently I am using 
data$at <- str_match(data$tweet_text,"\s@\w+")
data$hash <- str_match(data$tweet_text,"\s#\w+")

Which obviously gives me the first occurrence of each into a new variable.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsplit` and `grep` will work:

```
x <-strsplit("This is a test tweet using #twitter. @johnsmith @joesmith."," ")
grep("#|@",unlist(x), value=TRUE)
#[1] "#twitter."  "@johnsmith" "@joesmith."
```

If you only want to keep the words, no #,@ or .:

```
out <-grep("#|@",unlist(x), value=TRUE)
gsub("#|@|\\.","",out)
[1] "twitter"   "johnsmith" "joesmith"
```

**UPDATE** Putting the results in a `list`:

```
my_list <-NULL

x <-strsplit("This is a test tweet using #twitter. @johnsmith @joesmith."," ")
my_list$hash <-c(my_list$hash,gsub("#|@|\\.","",grep("#",unlist(x), value=TRUE)))
my_list$at <-c(my_list$at,gsub("#|@|\\.","",grep("@",unlist(x), value=TRUE)))

x <-strsplit("2nd tweet using #second. @jillsmith @joansmith."," ")
my_list$hash <-c(my_list$hash,gsub("#|@|\\.","",grep("#",unlist(x), value=TRUE)))
my_list$at <-c(my_list$at,gsub("#|@|\\.","",grep("@",unlist(x), value=TRUE)))

my_list
$hash
[1] "twitter" "second" 

$at
[1] "johnsmith" "joesmith"  "jillsmith" "joansmith"
```

Comment: That worked for pulling each expression.  Is there a way to put the output into new variables in the existing dataframe?

Comment: It would not work in a `data.frame` because you would be adding a different number of variables in the columns. For example, if you add "johnsmith" "joesmith" in the "at" column, what do you add in the same rows in the "hash" column? It would work in a `list`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: My initial thought was to do it separately.  Ideally I would like to have the code search the text for the first pattern with a @ sign and put it into a variable, then search again for another and put that in a second variable, and so on.  For rows that have less than others, input NA or something.

Failing that, I think your code will get me part of the way there and I can work something else out.